Conditional probability question's book solution does not match mine
I got confused when solving a conditional probabilty question from the book "Introduction to Probability" by Dimitri and Tsitsiklis.
Question is as follows:
Example 1.8. A conservative design team, call it C, and an innovative design
team, call it N, are asked to separately design a new product within a month. From
past experience we know that:
(a) The probability that team C is successful is 2/3.
(b) The probability that team N is successful is 1/2.
(c) The probability that at least one team is successful is 3/4.
If both teams are successful, the design of team N is adopted. Assuming that exactly
one successful design is produced, what is the probability that it was designed by
team N?
The book solution is:
enter image description here

I understand the book's solution but what I do not understand is why I get different answers(wrong ans) when I try to find the probabilities as follows ->

P(SS) = P(C=successful) * P(N=successfull) = 2/3 * 1/2

P(SF) = P(C=successful) * P(N=fail) = 2/3 * 1/2

P(FS) = P(C=fail) * P(N=successfull) = 1/3 0 1/2

P(FF) = P(C=fail) * P(N=fail) = 1/3 * 1/2*


as from the question I interpret it as the probability that C succeeds is 2/3 hence P(C=successfull) = 2/3 and, the probability that N succeeds is 1/2 hence, P(N=successfull)=1/2
Thank you very much for your help.

Nobody said the events ($C$ succeeds, $N$ succeeds) are independent.  Presumably they aren't...they both depend on the difficulty of the project, say.  Indeed, the given data excludes the possibility of independence.

@lulu had they said that those two events were independent could I have done it my way then ?

No, because the data contradicts independence.

@lulu I see thank you very much. Then my problem is that I cannot understand why "The probability that team C is successful is 2/3" cannot be interpreted as P(C=successfull) = 2/3 on its own ?

Obviously those two statements are the same.  I suggest:  Go over the problem  and its official solution carefully now that you see the problem with your computation.
